# Can I specialize a Foldable instance method based on the typeclass of a?

Tags: haskell

I have a `Foldable` container for `a`s. One of the methods provided by the `Foldable` typeclass in `BasicPrelude` is `elem :: (Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool`. Now, for my container, I can implement `elem` more efficiently than the default provided that my `a` is an `Ord` instance, but only in that case.

Now, I would like to have the more efficient `elem` available if possible, preferably with the same signature (i.e. 'transparently'). However, I can only see one way of doing this, which is to require an `(Ord a)` constraint on the `Foldable` instance for my container, which makes no sense in the general case.

Is it possible for me to have a specialized `elem` only for cases where `a` is an `Ord`, and a general `elem` for others somehow? I don't mind use of GHC extensions if that's what it takes.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use GHC `RULES` pragmas to specialize too specific types. This is ... not a sure bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It's a long-standing wart that the standard type classes aren't compatible with types that require restricted parameters.

Check out the [`monotraversable` library](https://www.stackage.org/lts-5.11/package/mono-traversable-0.10.1.1), though, and in particular its [`MonofoldableOrd` class](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.11/mono-traversable-0.10.1.1/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldableOrd), which might well be useful to you.  The `monotraversable` library is an alternative version of the `Foldable`/`Traversable` classes that has been written to work on containers with monomorphic element types (think `ByteString` or `Text`) or with class-restricted element types (think `Set`).

The library is a heavy user of the [`TypeFamilies` extension](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-12-type-families.html), so you may have to study that a bit—although the library source code should provide plenty of examples of how to use the extension.

Comment: I still don't understand why `MonoFoldable` uses type families instead of MPTCs with fundeps, which strike me as a more natural fit to the particular problem.